# 403 errors on wysiwyg/media folder and product images

Tags: magento2

Another developer ran rm -rf on the pub/static folder. After I cleared cache none of the images show up. Wysiwyg folder images and product images do not show up.

They come back as 403 errors.

Is that an htaccess issue?

Comment: Yes, add the stock .htaccess file from pub/static and everything should work (assuming you're using Apache as the webserver).

Comment: Do I need to clear or deploy anything?

Comment: Usually you do not. You could flush the Magento cache, but that should be it. If you're using varnish that cache may also need to be flushed if it cached the 403 errors.

Comment: 644 permission is ok?  The issue is still there.

Comment: Did you run bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy ? You need to run that as well I believe to generate content if in production mode...

Comment: I'm in developer.  I ran it anyway with -f

Comment: See if the files are being populated. Also, is a version being used. If so, you can turn off signing (core_config_data 'dev/static/sign'). Could try setup:upgrade as well.

Comment: A version is being used. I will try that.